# Strip off HTML attributes for all table elements

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML table

What I want is to get completely rid of all HTML attributes, so my table looks something, like:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>...</th>
            ...
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            ...
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I do that with plain JavaScript?

I have found several similar topics over here, but they either use jQuery (**which I'm not allowed to use**) or don't work for me.

```html
<table class="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;text-align: right">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-sort-type="number" class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Rank
      </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Country/Territory
      </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Int$
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/65/Flag_of_Qatar.svg/23px-Flag_of_Qatar.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/65/Flag_of_Qatar.svg/35px-Flag_of_Qatar.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/65/Flag_of_Qatar.svg/46px-Flag_of_Qatar.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1400" data-file-height="550" width="23" height="9">&nbsp;</span>
        <a
          href="/wiki/Qatar" title="Qatar">Qatar</a>
      </td>
      <td>128,378
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>—</td>
      <td align="left"><i><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/63/Flag_of_Macau.svg/23px-Flag_of_Macau.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/63/Flag_of_Macau.svg/35px-Flag_of_Macau.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/63/Flag_of_Macau.svg/45px-Flag_of_Macau.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="450" data-file-height="300" width="23" height="15">&nbsp;</span><a href="/wiki/Macau" title="Macau">Macau</a></i></td>
      <td>115,123
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/da/Flag_of_Luxembourg.svg/23px-Flag_of_Luxembourg.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/da/Flag_of_Luxembourg.svg/35px-Flag_of_Luxembourg.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/da/Flag_of_Luxembourg.svg/46px-Flag_of_Luxembourg.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1000" data-file-height="600" width="23" height="14">&nbsp;</span>
        <a
          href="/wiki/Luxembourg" title="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</a>
      </td>
      <td>103,662
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/48/Flag_of_Singapore.svg/23px-Flag_of_Singapore.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/48/Flag_of_Singapore.svg/35px-Flag_of_Singapore.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/48/Flag_of_Singapore.svg/45px-Flag_of_Singapore.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="4320" data-file-height="2880" width="23" height="15">&nbsp;</span>
        <a
          href="/wiki/Singapore" title="Singapore">Singapore</a>
      </td>
      <td>93,905
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/Flag_of_Brunei.svg/23px-Flag_of_Brunei.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/Flag_of_Brunei.svg/35px-Flag_of_Brunei.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/Flag_of_Brunei.svg/46px-Flag_of_Brunei.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1440" data-file-height="720" width="23" height="12">&nbsp;</span>
        <a
          href="/wiki/Brunei" title="Brunei">Brunei</a>
      </td>
      <td>78,836
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/Flag_of_Ireland.svg/23px-Flag_of_Ireland.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/Flag_of_Ireland.svg/35px-Flag_of_Ireland.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/Flag_of_Ireland.svg/46px-Flag_of_Ireland.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1200" data-file-height="600" width="23" height="12">&nbsp;</span>
        <a
          href="/wiki/Republic_of_Ireland" title="Republic of Ireland">Ireland</a>
      </td>
      <td>76,305
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/Flag_of_the_United_Arab_Emirates.svg/23px-Flag_of_the_United_Arab_Emirates.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/Flag_of_the_United_Arab_Emirates.svg/35px-Flag_of_the_United_Arab_Emirates.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/Flag_of_the_United_Arab_Emirates.svg/46px-Flag_of_the_United_Arab_Emirates.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1200" data-file-height="600" width="23" height="12">&nbsp;</span>
        <a
          href="/wiki/United_Arab_Emirates" title="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</a>
      </td>
      <td>73,879
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7
      </td>
      <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Flag_of_Kuwait.svg/23px-Flag_of_Kuwait.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Flag_of_Kuwait.svg/35px-Flag_of_Kuwait.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Flag_of_Kuwait.svg/46px-Flag_of_Kuwait.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1200" data-file-height="600" width="23" height="12">&nbsp;</span>
        <a
          href="/wiki/Kuwait" title="Kuwait">Kuwait</a>
      </td>
      <td>71,943
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f3/Flag_of_Switzerland.svg/16px-Flag_of_Switzerland.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f3/Flag_of_Switzerland.svg/24px-Flag_of_Switzerland.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f3/Flag_of_Switzerland.svg/32px-Flag_of_Switzerland.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1000" data-file-height="1000" width="16" height="16">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
        <a
          href="/wiki/Switzerland" title="Switzerland">Switzerland</a>
      </td>
      <td>65,006
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9
      </td>
      <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b1/Flag_of_San_Marino.svg/20px-Flag_of_San_Marino.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b1/Flag_of_San_Marino.svg/31px-Flag_of_San_Marino.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b1/Flag_of_San_Marino.svg/40px-Flag_of_San_Marino.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="800" data-file-height="600" width="20" height="15">&nbsp;</span>
        <a
          href="/wiki/San_Marino" title="San Marino">San Marino</a>
      </td>
      <td>62,425
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>—</td>
      <td align="left"><i><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5b/Flag_of_Hong_Kong.svg/23px-Flag_of_Hong_Kong.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5b/Flag_of_Hong_Kong.svg/35px-Flag_of_Hong_Kong.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5b/Flag_of_Hong_Kong.svg/45px-Flag_of_Hong_Kong.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="900" data-file-height="600" width="23" height="15">&nbsp;</span><a href="/wiki/Hong_Kong" title="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</a></i></td>
      <td>61,540
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d9/Flag_of_Norway.svg/21px-Flag_of_Norway.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d9/Flag_of_Norway.svg/32px-Flag_of_Norway.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d9/Flag_of_Norway.svg/41px-Flag_of_Norway.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1100" data-file-height="800" width="21" height="15">&nbsp;</span>
        <a
          href="/wiki/Norway" title="Norway">Norway</a>
      </td>
      <td>60,978
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg/23px-Flag_of_the_United_States.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg/35px-Flag_of_the_United_States.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg/46px-Flag_of_the_United_States.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1235" data-file-height="650" width="23" height="12">&nbsp;</span>
        <a
          href="/wiki/United_States" title="United States">United States</a>
      </td>
      <td>59,532
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/Flag_of_Saudi_Arabia.svg/23px-Flag_of_Saudi_Arabia.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/Flag_of_Saudi_Arabia.svg/35px-Flag_of_Saudi_Arabia.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/Flag_of_Saudi_Arabia.svg/45px-Flag_of_Saudi_Arabia.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="900" data-file-height="600" width="23" height="15">&nbsp;</span>
        <a
          href="/wiki/Saudi_Arabia" title="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</a>
      </td>
      <td>53,845
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13</td>
      <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/ce/Flag_of_Iceland.svg/21px-Flag_of_Iceland.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/ce/Flag_of_Iceland.svg/32px-Flag_of_Iceland.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/ce/Flag_of_Iceland.svg/42px-Flag_of_Iceland.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="800" data-file-height="576" width="21" height="15">&nbsp;</span>
        <a
          href="/wiki/Iceland" title="Iceland">Iceland</a>
      </td>
      <td>53,518
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>14</td>
      <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Flag_of_the_Netherlands.svg/23px-Flag_of_the_Netherlands.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Flag_of_the_Netherlands.svg/35px-Flag_of_the_Netherlands.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Flag_of_the_Netherlands.svg/45px-Flag_of_the_Netherlands.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="900" data-file-height="600" width="23" height="15">&nbsp;</span>
        <a
          href="/wiki/Netherlands" title="Netherlands">Netherlands</a>
      </td>
      <td>52,941
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>15</td>
      <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Flag_of_Austria.svg/23px-Flag_of_Austria.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Flag_of_Austria.svg/35px-Flag_of_Austria.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Flag_of_Austria.svg/45px-Flag_of_Austria.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="900" data-file-height="600" width="23" height="15">&nbsp;</span>
        <a
          href="/wiki/Austria" title="Austria">Austria</a>
      </td>
      <td>52,558
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>16</td>
      <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/b/ba/Flag_of_Germany.svg/23px-Flag_of_Germany.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/b/ba/Flag_of_Germany.svg/35px-Flag_of_Germany.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/b/ba/Flag_of_Germany.svg/46px-Flag_of_Germany.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1000" data-file-height="600" width="23" height="14">&nbsp;</span>
        <a
          href="/wiki/Germany" title="Germany">Germany</a>
      </td>
      <td>50,715
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>17</td>
      <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/Flag_of_Denmark.svg/20px-Flag_of_Denmark.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/Flag_of_Denmark.svg/31px-Flag_of_Denmark.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/Flag_of_Denmark.svg/40px-Flag_of_Denmark.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="740" data-file-height="560" width="20" height="15">&nbsp;</span>
        <a
          href="/wiki/Denmark" title="Denmark">Denmark</a>
      </td>
      <td>50,541
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>18</td>
      <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/4c/Flag_of_Sweden.svg/23px-Flag_of_Sweden.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/4c/Flag_of_Sweden.svg/35px-Flag_of_Sweden.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/4c/Flag_of_Sweden.svg/46px-Flag_of_Sweden.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1600" data-file-height="1000" width="23" height="14">&nbsp;</span>
        <a
          href="/wiki/Sweden" title="Sweden">Sweden</a>
      </td>
      <td>50,070
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>19</td>
      <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Flag_of_Belgium_%28civil%29.svg/23px-Flag_of_Belgium_%28civil%29.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Flag_of_Belgium_%28civil%29.svg/35px-Flag_of_Belgium_%28civil%29.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Flag_of_Belgium_%28civil%29.svg/45px-Flag_of_Belgium_%28civil%29.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="450" data-file-height="300" width="23" height="15">&nbsp;</span>
        <a
          href="/wiki/Belgium" title="Belgium">Belgium</a>
      </td>
      <td>47,561
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>20
      </td>
      <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/Flag_of_Bahrain.svg/23px-Flag_of_Bahrain.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/Flag_of_Bahrain.svg/35px-Flag_of_Bahrain.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/Flag_of_Bahrain.svg/46px-Flag_of_Bahrain.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1500" data-file-height="900" width="23" height="14">&nbsp;</span>
        <a
          href="/wiki/Bahrain" title="Bahrain">Bahrain</a>
      </td>
      <td>47,527
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>21</td>
      <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/88/Flag_of_Australia_%28converted%29.svg/23px-Flag_of_Australia_%28converted%29.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/88/Flag_of_Australia_%28converted%29.svg/35px-Flag_of_Australia_%28converted%29.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/88/Flag_of_Australia_%28converted%29.svg/46px-Flag_of_Australia_%28converted%29.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1280" data-file-height="640" width="23" height="12">&nbsp;</span>
        <a
          href="/wiki/Australia" title="Australia">Australia</a>
      </td>
      <td>47,047
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: so you want to remove all attributes ?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee : yes! exactly

Comment: So WHAT did you try? Select all the rows, read all the attributes, loop over them, and remove them.

Comment: @epascarello if OP could do that and find how to do it, he would have, no? It is not so trivial.

Comment: @mplungjan and with your answer and the other answer you basically did their homework/job for them. Problem is, person probably did not think about doing it in pieces so they got stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may iterate over all nodes and get their attribute names with [`.getAttributeNames()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttributeNames), which you can remove, using [`.removeAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute):

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('*')].forEach(node => node.getAttributeNames().forEach(attr => node.removeAttribute(attr)))
```

```html
<table class="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;text-align: right">
<thead><tr>
<th data-sort-type="number" class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Rank
</th>
<th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Country/Territory
</th>
<th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Int$
</th></tr></thead><tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/65/Flag_of_Qatar.svg/23px-Flag_of_Qatar.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/65/Flag_of_Qatar.svg/35px-Flag_of_Qatar.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/65/Flag_of_Qatar.svg/46px-Flag_of_Qatar.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1400" data-file-height="550" width="23" height="9">&nbsp;</span><a href="/wiki/Qatar" title="Qatar">Qatar</a></td>
<td>128,378
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>—</td>
<td align="left"><i><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/63/Flag_of_Macau.svg/23px-Flag_of_Macau.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/63/Flag_of_Macau.svg/35px-Flag_of_Macau.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/63/Flag_of_Macau.svg/45px-Flag_of_Macau.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="450" data-file-height="300" width="23" height="15">&nbsp;</span><a href="/wiki/Macau" title="Macau">Macau</a></i></td>
<td>115,123
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/da/Flag_of_Luxembourg.svg/23px-Flag_of_Luxembourg.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/da/Flag_of_Luxembourg.svg/35px-Flag_of_Luxembourg.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/da/Flag_of_Luxembourg.svg/46px-Flag_of_Luxembourg.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1000" data-file-height="600" width="23" height="14">&nbsp;</span><a href="/wiki/Luxembourg" title="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</a></td>
<td>103,662
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/48/Flag_of_Singapore.svg/23px-Flag_of_Singapore.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/48/Flag_of_Singapore.svg/35px-Flag_of_Singapore.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/48/Flag_of_Singapore.svg/45px-Flag_of_Singapore.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="4320" data-file-height="2880" width="23" height="15">&nbsp;</span><a href="/wiki/Singapore" title="Singapore">Singapore</a></td>
<td>93,905
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/Flag_of_Brunei.svg/23px-Flag_of_Brunei.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/Flag_of_Brunei.svg/35px-Flag_of_Brunei.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/Flag_of_Brunei.svg/46px-Flag_of_Brunei.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1440" data-file-height="720" width="23" height="12">&nbsp;</span><a href="/wiki/Brunei" title="Brunei">Brunei</a></td>
<td>78,836
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>5</td>
<td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/Flag_of_Ireland.svg/23px-Flag_of_Ireland.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/Flag_of_Ireland.svg/35px-Flag_of_Ireland.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/Flag_of_Ireland.svg/46px-Flag_of_Ireland.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1200" data-file-height="600" width="23" height="12">&nbsp;</span><a href="/wiki/Republic_of_Ireland" title="Republic of Ireland">Ireland</a></td>
<td>76,305
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>6</td>
<td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/Flag_of_the_United_Arab_Emirates.svg/23px-Flag_of_the_United_Arab_Emirates.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/Flag_of_the_United_Arab_Emirates.svg/35px-Flag_of_the_United_Arab_Emirates.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/Flag_of_the_United_Arab_Emirates.svg/46px-Flag_of_the_United_Arab_Emirates.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1200" data-file-height="600" width="23" height="12">&nbsp;</span><a href="/wiki/United_Arab_Emirates" title="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</a></td>
<td>73,879
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>7
</td>
<td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Flag_of_Kuwait.svg/23px-Flag_of_Kuwait.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Flag_of_Kuwait.svg/35px-Flag_of_Kuwait.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Flag_of_Kuwait.svg/46px-Flag_of_Kuwait.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1200" data-file-height="600" width="23" height="12">&nbsp;</span><a href="/wiki/Kuwait" title="Kuwait">Kuwait</a>
</td>
<td>71,943
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>8</td>
<td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f3/Flag_of_Switzerland.svg/16px-Flag_of_Switzerland.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f3/Flag_of_Switzerland.svg/24px-Flag_of_Switzerland.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f3/Flag_of_Switzerland.svg/32px-Flag_of_Switzerland.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1000" data-file-height="1000" width="16" height="16">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a href="/wiki/Switzerland" title="Switzerland">Switzerland</a></td>
<td>65,006
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>9
</td>
<td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b1/Flag_of_San_Marino.svg/20px-Flag_of_San_Marino.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b1/Flag_of_San_Marino.svg/31px-Flag_of_San_Marino.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b1/Flag_of_San_Marino.svg/40px-Flag_of_San_Marino.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="800" data-file-height="600" width="20" height="15">&nbsp;</span><a href="/wiki/San_Marino" title="San Marino">San Marino</a>
</td>
<td>62,425
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>—</td>
<td align="left"><i><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5b/Flag_of_Hong_Kong.svg/23px-Flag_of_Hong_Kong.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5b/Flag_of_Hong_Kong.svg/35px-Flag_of_Hong_Kong.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5b/Flag_of_Hong_Kong.svg/45px-Flag_of_Hong_Kong.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="900" data-file-height="600" width="23" height="15">&nbsp;</span><a href="/wiki/Hong_Kong" title="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</a></i></td>
<td>61,540
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>10</td>
<td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d9/Flag_of_Norway.svg/21px-Flag_of_Norway.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d9/Flag_of_Norway.svg/32px-Flag_of_Norway.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d9/Flag_of_Norway.svg/41px-Flag_of_Norway.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1100" data-file-height="800" width="21" height="15">&nbsp;</span><a href="/wiki/Norway" title="Norway">Norway</a></td>
<td>60,978
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>11</td>
<td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg/23px-Flag_of_the_United_States.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg/35px-Flag_of_the_United_States.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg/46px-Flag_of_the_United_States.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1235" data-file-height="650" width="23" height="12">&nbsp;</span><a href="/wiki/United_States" title="United States">United States</a></td>
<td>59,532
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>12</td>
<td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/Flag_of_Saudi_Arabia.svg/23px-Flag_of_Saudi_Arabia.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/Flag_of_Saudi_Arabia.svg/35px-Flag_of_Saudi_Arabia.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/Flag_of_Saudi_Arabia.svg/45px-Flag_of_Saudi_Arabia.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="900" data-file-height="600" width="23" height="15">&nbsp;</span><a href="/wiki/Saudi_Arabia" title="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</a></td>
<td>53,845
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>13</td>
<td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/ce/Flag_of_Iceland.svg/21px-Flag_of_Iceland.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/ce/Flag_of_Iceland.svg/32px-Flag_of_Iceland.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/ce/Flag_of_Iceland.svg/42px-Flag_of_Iceland.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="800" data-file-height="576" width="21" height="15">&nbsp;</span><a href="/wiki/Iceland" title="Iceland">Iceland</a></td>
<td>53,518
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>14</td>
<td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Flag_of_the_Netherlands.svg/23px-Flag_of_the_Netherlands.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Flag_of_the_Netherlands.svg/35px-Flag_of_the_Netherlands.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Flag_of_the_Netherlands.svg/45px-Flag_of_the_Netherlands.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="900" data-file-height="600" width="23" height="15">&nbsp;</span><a href="/wiki/Netherlands" title="Netherlands">Netherlands</a></td>
<td>52,941
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>15</td>
<td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Flag_of_Austria.svg/23px-Flag_of_Austria.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Flag_of_Austria.svg/35px-Flag_of_Austria.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Flag_of_Austria.svg/45px-Flag_of_Austria.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="900" data-file-height="600" width="23" height="15">&nbsp;</span><a href="/wiki/Austria" title="Austria">Austria</a></td>
<td>52,558
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>16</td>
<td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/b/ba/Flag_of_Germany.svg/23px-Flag_of_Germany.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/b/ba/Flag_of_Germany.svg/35px-Flag_of_Germany.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/b/ba/Flag_of_Germany.svg/46px-Flag_of_Germany.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1000" data-file-height="600" width="23" height="14">&nbsp;</span><a href="/wiki/Germany" title="Germany">Germany</a></td>
<td>50,715
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>17</td>
<td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/Flag_of_Denmark.svg/20px-Flag_of_Denmark.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/Flag_of_Denmark.svg/31px-Flag_of_Denmark.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/Flag_of_Denmark.svg/40px-Flag_of_Denmark.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="740" data-file-height="560" width="20" height="15">&nbsp;</span><a href="/wiki/Denmark" title="Denmark">Denmark</a></td>
<td>50,541
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>18</td>
<td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/4c/Flag_of_Sweden.svg/23px-Flag_of_Sweden.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/4c/Flag_of_Sweden.svg/35px-Flag_of_Sweden.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/4c/Flag_of_Sweden.svg/46px-Flag_of_Sweden.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1600" data-file-height="1000" width="23" height="14">&nbsp;</span><a href="/wiki/Sweden" title="Sweden">Sweden</a></td>
<td>50,070
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>19</td>
<td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Flag_of_Belgium_%28civil%29.svg/23px-Flag_of_Belgium_%28civil%29.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Flag_of_Belgium_%28civil%29.svg/35px-Flag_of_Belgium_%28civil%29.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Flag_of_Belgium_%28civil%29.svg/45px-Flag_of_Belgium_%28civil%29.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="450" data-file-height="300" width="23" height="15">&nbsp;</span><a href="/wiki/Belgium" title="Belgium">Belgium</a></td>
<td>47,561
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>20
</td>
<td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/Flag_of_Bahrain.svg/23px-Flag_of_Bahrain.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/Flag_of_Bahrain.svg/35px-Flag_of_Bahrain.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/Flag_of_Bahrain.svg/46px-Flag_of_Bahrain.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1500" data-file-height="900" width="23" height="14">&nbsp;</span><a href="/wiki/Bahrain" title="Bahrain">Bahrain</a>
</td>
<td>47,527
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>21</td>
<td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/88/Flag_of_Australia_%28converted%29.svg/23px-Flag_of_Australia_%28converted%29.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/88/Flag_of_Australia_%28converted%29.svg/35px-Flag_of_Australia_%28converted%29.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/88/Flag_of_Australia_%28converted%29.svg/46px-Flag_of_Australia_%28converted%29.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1280" data-file-height="640" width="23" height="12">&nbsp;</span><a href="/wiki/Australia" title="Australia">Australia</a></td>
<td>47,047
</td></tr>
</tbody><tfoot></tfoot></table>
```

Comment: That works perfectly. But is there a way to remove those `<span>` elements with flags, so I get my table entirely clean?

Comment: If you want to remove certain node types (`<span>` in your case) along with all attributes, you may run `[...document.querySelectorAll('table span')].forEach(span => span.remove())` or insert something like `if(node.tagName == 'SPAN') node.remove()` into my initial answer

Answer (score 2):

Like this - I assume you want to keep the image src and the href

I have shortened the table to stay within SO limits

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#tableContainer *").forEach(function(tag) {
  [...tag.attributes].forEach(function(attr) {
    if (["href","src"].indexOf(attr.name) ==-1) tag.removeAttribute(attr.name)
  })
})
// console.log(document.querySelector("#tableContainer").innerHTML)
```

```html
<div id="tableContainer">
  <table class="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;text-align: right">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-sort-type="number" class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Rank
        </th>
        <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Country/Territory
        </th>
        <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Int$
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/65/Flag_of_Qatar.svg/23px-Flag_of_Qatar.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/65/Flag_of_Qatar.svg/35px-Flag_of_Qatar.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/65/Flag_of_Qatar.svg/46px-Flag_of_Qatar.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1400" data-file-height="550" width="23" height="9">&nbsp;</span>
          <a href="/wiki/Qatar" title="Qatar">Qatar</a>
        </td>
        <td>128,378
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>—</td>
        <td align="left"><i><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/63/Flag_of_Macau.svg/23px-Flag_of_Macau.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/63/Flag_of_Macau.svg/35px-Flag_of_Macau.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/63/Flag_of_Macau.svg/45px-Flag_of_Macau.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="450" data-file-height="300" width="23" height="15">&nbsp;</span><a href="/wiki/Macau" title="Macau">Macau</a></i></td>
        <td>115,123
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/da/Flag_of_Luxembourg.svg/23px-Flag_of_Luxembourg.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/da/Flag_of_Luxembourg.svg/35px-Flag_of_Luxembourg.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/da/Flag_of_Luxembourg.svg/46px-Flag_of_Luxembourg.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1000" data-file-height="600" width="23" height="14">&nbsp;</span>
          <a href="/wiki/Luxembourg" title="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</a>
        </td>
        <td>103,662
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/48/Flag_of_Singapore.svg/23px-Flag_of_Singapore.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/48/Flag_of_Singapore.svg/35px-Flag_of_Singapore.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/48/Flag_of_Singapore.svg/45px-Flag_of_Singapore.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="4320" data-file-height="2880" width="23" height="15">&nbsp;</span>
          <a href="/wiki/Singapore" title="Singapore">Singapore</a>
        </td>
        <td>93,905
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/Flag_of_Brunei.svg/23px-Flag_of_Brunei.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/Flag_of_Brunei.svg/35px-Flag_of_Brunei.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/Flag_of_Brunei.svg/46px-Flag_of_Brunei.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1440" data-file-height="720" width="23" height="12">&nbsp;</span>
          <a href="/wiki/Brunei" title="Brunei">Brunei</a>
        </td>
        <td>78,836
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/Flag_of_Ireland.svg/23px-Flag_of_Ireland.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/Flag_of_Ireland.svg/35px-Flag_of_Ireland.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/Flag_of_Ireland.svg/46px-Flag_of_Ireland.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1200" data-file-height="600" width="23" height="12">&nbsp;</span>
          <a href="/wiki/Republic_of_Ireland" title="Republic of Ireland">Ireland</a>
        </td>
        <td>76,305
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/Flag_of_the_United_Arab_Emirates.svg/23px-Flag_of_the_United_Arab_Emirates.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/Flag_of_the_United_Arab_Emirates.svg/35px-Flag_of_the_United_Arab_Emirates.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/Flag_of_the_United_Arab_Emirates.svg/46px-Flag_of_the_United_Arab_Emirates.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1200" data-file-height="600" width="23" height="12">&nbsp;</span>
          <a href="/wiki/United_Arab_Emirates" title="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</a>
        </td>
        <td>73,879
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7
        </td>
        <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Flag_of_Kuwait.svg/23px-Flag_of_Kuwait.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Flag_of_Kuwait.svg/35px-Flag_of_Kuwait.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Flag_of_Kuwait.svg/46px-Flag_of_Kuwait.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1200" data-file-height="600" width="23" height="12">&nbsp;</span>
          <a href="/wiki/Kuwait" title="Kuwait">Kuwait</a>
        </td>
        <td>71,943
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f3/Flag_of_Switzerland.svg/16px-Flag_of_Switzerland.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f3/Flag_of_Switzerland.svg/24px-Flag_of_Switzerland.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f3/Flag_of_Switzerland.svg/32px-Flag_of_Switzerland.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1000" data-file-height="1000" width="16" height="16">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
          <a href="/wiki/Switzerland" title="Switzerland">Switzerland</a>
        </td>
        <td>65,006
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9
        </td>
        <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b1/Flag_of_San_Marino.svg/20px-Flag_of_San_Marino.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b1/Flag_of_San_Marino.svg/31px-Flag_of_San_Marino.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b1/Flag_of_San_Marino.svg/40px-Flag_of_San_Marino.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="800" data-file-height="600" width="20" height="15">&nbsp;</span>
          <a href="/wiki/San_Marino" title="San Marino">San Marino</a>
        </td>
        <td>62,425
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>—</td>
        <td align="left"><i><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5b/Flag_of_Hong_Kong.svg/23px-Flag_of_Hong_Kong.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5b/Flag_of_Hong_Kong.svg/35px-Flag_of_Hong_Kong.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5b/Flag_of_Hong_Kong.svg/45px-Flag_of_Hong_Kong.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="900" data-file-height="600" width="23" height="15">&nbsp;</span><a href="/wiki/Hong_Kong" title="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</a></i></td>
        <td>61,540
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d9/Flag_of_Norway.svg/21px-Flag_of_Norway.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d9/Flag_of_Norway.svg/32px-Flag_of_Norway.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d9/Flag_of_Norway.svg/41px-Flag_of_Norway.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1100" data-file-height="800" width="21" height="15">&nbsp;</span>
          <a href="/wiki/Norway" title="Norway">Norway</a>
        </td>
        <td>60,978
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg/23px-Flag_of_the_United_States.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg/35px-Flag_of_the_United_States.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg/46px-Flag_of_the_United_States.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1235" data-file-height="650" width="23" height="12">&nbsp;</span>
          <a href="/wiki/United_States" title="United States">United States</a>
        </td>
        <td>59,532
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/Flag_of_Saudi_Arabia.svg/23px-Flag_of_Saudi_Arabia.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/Flag_of_Saudi_Arabia.svg/35px-Flag_of_Saudi_Arabia.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/Flag_of_Saudi_Arabia.svg/45px-Flag_of_Saudi_Arabia.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="900" data-file-height="600" width="23" height="15">&nbsp;</span>
          <a href="/wiki/Saudi_Arabia" title="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</a>
        </td>
        <td>53,845
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>13</td>
        <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/ce/Flag_of_Iceland.svg/21px-Flag_of_Iceland.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/ce/Flag_of_Iceland.svg/32px-Flag_of_Iceland.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/ce/Flag_of_Iceland.svg/42px-Flag_of_Iceland.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="800" data-file-height="576" width="21" height="15">&nbsp;</span>
          <a href="/wiki/Iceland" title="Iceland">Iceland</a>
        </td>
        <td>53,518
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>14</td>
        <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Flag_of_the_Netherlands.svg/23px-Flag_of_the_Netherlands.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Flag_of_the_Netherlands.svg/35px-Flag_of_the_Netherlands.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Flag_of_the_Netherlands.svg/45px-Flag_of_the_Netherlands.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="900" data-file-height="600" width="23" height="15">&nbsp;</span>
          <a href="/wiki/Netherlands" title="Netherlands">Netherlands</a>
        </td>
        <td>52,941
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>15</td>
        <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Flag_of_Austria.svg/23px-Flag_of_Austria.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Flag_of_Austria.svg/35px-Flag_of_Austria.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Flag_of_Austria.svg/45px-Flag_of_Austria.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="900" data-file-height="600" width="23" height="15">&nbsp;</span>
          <a href="/wiki/Austria" title="Austria">Austria</a>
        </td>
        <td>52,558
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>16</td>
        <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/b/ba/Flag_of_Germany.svg/23px-Flag_of_Germany.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/b/ba/Flag_of_Germany.svg/35px-Flag_of_Germany.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/b/ba/Flag_of_Germany.svg/46px-Flag_of_Germany.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1000" data-file-height="600" width="23" height="14">&nbsp;</span>
          <a href="/wiki/Germany" title="Germany">Germany</a>
        </td>
        <td>50,715
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>17</td>
        <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/Flag_of_Denmark.svg/20px-Flag_of_Denmark.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/Flag_of_Denmark.svg/31px-Flag_of_Denmark.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/Flag_of_Denmark.svg/40px-Flag_of_Denmark.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="740" data-file-height="560" width="20" height="15">&nbsp;</span>
          <a href="/wiki/Denmark" title="Denmark">Denmark</a>
        </td>
        <td>50,541
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>18</td>
        <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/4c/Flag_of_Sweden.svg/23px-Flag_of_Sweden.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/4c/Flag_of_Sweden.svg/35px-Flag_of_Sweden.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/4c/Flag_of_Sweden.svg/46px-Flag_of_Sweden.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1600" data-file-height="1000" width="23" height="14">&nbsp;</span>
          <a href="/wiki/Sweden" title="Sweden">Sweden</a>
        </td>
        <td>50,070
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>19</td>
        <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Flag_of_Belgium_%28civil%29.svg/23px-Flag_of_Belgium_%28civil%29.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Flag_of_Belgium_%28civil%29.svg/35px-Flag_of_Belgium_%28civil%29.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Flag_of_Belgium_%28civil%29.svg/45px-Flag_of_Belgium_%28civil%29.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="450" data-file-height="300" width="23" height="15">&nbsp;</span>
          <a href="/wiki/Belgium" title="Belgium">Belgium</a>
        </td>
        <td>47,561
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>20
        </td>
        <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/Flag_of_Bahrain.svg/23px-Flag_of_Bahrain.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/Flag_of_Bahrain.svg/35px-Flag_of_Bahrain.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/Flag_of_Bahrain.svg/46px-Flag_of_Bahrain.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1500" data-file-height="900" width="23" height="14">&nbsp;</span>
          <a href="/wiki/Bahrain" title="Bahrain">Bahrain</a>
        </td>
        <td>47,527
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>21</td>
        <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/88/Flag_of_Australia_%28converted%29.svg/23px-Flag_of_Australia_%28converted%29.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/88/Flag_of_Australia_%28converted%29.svg/35px-Flag_of_Australia_%28converted%29.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/88/Flag_of_Australia_%28converted%29.svg/46px-Flag_of_Australia_%28converted%29.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1280" data-file-height="640" width="23" height="12">&nbsp;</span>
          <a href="/wiki/Australia" title="Australia">Australia</a>
        </td>
        <td>47,047
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot></tfoot>
  </table>
</DIV>
```

If you just want to keep the name of the country:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#tableContainer *").forEach(function(tag) {
  if (tag.tagName.toUpperCase() ==="SPAN") tag.remove(); 
  else if (tag.tagName.toUpperCase() ==="A") tag.parentNode.textContent = tag.getAttribute("title");
  else {
    [...tag.attributes].forEach(function(attr) {
      if (["href","src"].indexOf(attr.name) ==-1) tag.removeAttribute(attr.name);
    })
  }  
})
// console.log(document.querySelector("#tableContainer").innerHTML)
```

```html
<div id="tableContainer">
  <table class="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;text-align: right">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-sort-type="number" class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Rank
        </th>
        <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Country/Territory
        </th>
        <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Int$
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/65/Flag_of_Qatar.svg/23px-Flag_of_Qatar.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/65/Flag_of_Qatar.svg/35px-Flag_of_Qatar.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/65/Flag_of_Qatar.svg/46px-Flag_of_Qatar.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1400" data-file-height="550" width="23" height="9">&nbsp;</span>
          <a href="/wiki/Qatar" title="Qatar">Qatar</a>
        </td>
        <td>128,378
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>—</td>
        <td align="left"><i><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/63/Flag_of_Macau.svg/23px-Flag_of_Macau.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/63/Flag_of_Macau.svg/35px-Flag_of_Macau.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/63/Flag_of_Macau.svg/45px-Flag_of_Macau.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="450" data-file-height="300" width="23" height="15">&nbsp;</span><a href="/wiki/Macau" title="Macau">Macau</a></i></td>
        <td>115,123
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/da/Flag_of_Luxembourg.svg/23px-Flag_of_Luxembourg.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/da/Flag_of_Luxembourg.svg/35px-Flag_of_Luxembourg.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/da/Flag_of_Luxembourg.svg/46px-Flag_of_Luxembourg.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1000" data-file-height="600" width="23" height="14">&nbsp;</span>
          <a href="/wiki/Luxembourg" title="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</a>
        </td>
        <td>103,662
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/48/Flag_of_Singapore.svg/23px-Flag_of_Singapore.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/48/Flag_of_Singapore.svg/35px-Flag_of_Singapore.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/48/Flag_of_Singapore.svg/45px-Flag_of_Singapore.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="4320" data-file-height="2880" width="23" height="15">&nbsp;</span>
          <a href="/wiki/Singapore" title="Singapore">Singapore</a>
        </td>
        <td>93,905
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/Flag_of_Brunei.svg/23px-Flag_of_Brunei.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/Flag_of_Brunei.svg/35px-Flag_of_Brunei.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/Flag_of_Brunei.svg/46px-Flag_of_Brunei.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1440" data-file-height="720" width="23" height="12">&nbsp;</span>
          <a href="/wiki/Brunei" title="Brunei">Brunei</a>
        </td>
        <td>78,836
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td align="left"><span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/Flag_of_Ireland.svg/23px-Flag_of_Ireland.svg.png" decoding="async" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/Flag_of_Ireland.svg/35px-Flag_of_Ireland.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/Flag_of_Ireland.svg/46px-Flag_of_Ireland.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="1200" data-file-height="600" width="23" height="12">&nbsp;</span>
          <a href="/wiki/Republic_of_Ireland" title="Republic of Ireland">Ireland</a>
        </td>
        <td>76,305
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot></tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```